# How to search for an array length in ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

Let say I have a schema

```
defmodule User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :loved_numbers, {:array, :integer} 
  end
end
```

How could I search using `Ecto.Query` for all users who have exactly 2 `loved_numbers`?

Would this query work in both PostgreSQL and MySQL?

Comment: I imagine that you are gonna have to use fragments and it's not gonna work both in PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PostgreSQL, you can use the `array_length` function using a fragment:

```
from(u in User, where: fragment("array_length(?, 1)", u.loved_numbers) == 2)
```

(The `1` is for the dimension to count, which should be `1` for one dimensional array.)

As far as I know, [MySQL does not support arrays](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1602).